# Dynamic progress bar in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, progress-bar

So I'm trying to build a progress bar that every time the user press a button the progress bar adds +1%.

html

```
<ion-button *ngFor="let progress of progress" (click)="add(progress)">Progress</ion-button>
<ion-progress-bar value={{progress}} buffer={{buffer}}></ion-progress-bar>
```

component file

```
add(progress){
    this.progress = progress + 1;

  }
```

For some reason the button is not showing but Logcat show no erros. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```js
public progress = 1;
public increaseProgress(){
  this.progress = this.progress + 1; 
}
```

```html
<ion-button (click)="increaseProgress()">Progress</ion-button>
<ion-progress-bar value={{progress}}></ion-progress-bar>
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. How can i Allow only integer numbers? Like, if my progress bar increase 1,56% each click, how can I show only the integer number?

Comment: You should use this instead of `{{}}`:

```<ion-progress-bar [value]="progress"></ion-progress-bar>```

Comment: Also, you need the total: ```<ion-progress-bar [value]="progress/total" [buffer]="buffer/total"></ion-progress-bar>```

Answer (score 0):

> You can follow this way, Is Working Well

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(public _zone: NgZone) { }

const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

fileTransfer.onProgress((progressEvent) => {
   this._zone.run(() => {
      this.progress = (progressEvent.lengthComputable) ?  
      Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100) : -1;
   });
 });



 <div class="progress-outer" >
    <progress id="progressbar" max="100" [value]="progress"> </progress>
 </div>
```